# Get data from treeview in tkinter

Tags: tkinter, get, treeview

I'm trying to get data from a Treeview I filled with :

```
self.tree['show'] = 'headings'
    self.tree['columns'] = ('Pool ID','Time', 'Lat', 'Lon', 'Alt', 'Spd', 'hdop','vdop','pdop', 'Sats Used', 'FixMode')
    self.tree.column('Pool ID', width=90, anchor='center')
    self.tree.heading('Pool ID', text='Pool ID')
    self.tree.column('Time', width=90, anchor='center')
    self.tree.heading('Time', text='Time')
    self.tree.column('Lat', width=90, anchor='center')
    self.tree.heading('Lat', text='Lat')
    self.tree.column('Lon', width=90, anchor='center')
    self.tree.heading('Lon', text='Lon')
    self.tree.column('Alt', width=90, anchor='center')
    self.tree.heading('Alt', text='Alt')
    self.tree.column('Spd', width=90, anchor='center')
    self.tree.heading('Spd', text='Spd')
    self.tree.column('hdop', width=90, anchor='center')
    self.tree.heading('hdop', text='hdop')
    self.tree.column('vdop', width=90, anchor='center')
    self.tree.heading('vdop', text='vdop')
    self.tree.column('pdop', width=90, anchor='center')
    self.tree.heading('pdop', text='pdop')
    self.tree.column('Sats Used', width=90, anchor='center')
    self.tree.heading('Sats Used', text='Sats Used')
    self.tree.column('FixMode', width=90, anchor='center')
    self.tree.heading('FixMode', text='FixMode')

    for i in range(5):

        self.tree.insert('', -1, values=(
                                           i+1,
                                           i+2, 
                                           i+3, 
                                           i+4,
                                           i+5,
                                           i+6,
                                           i+7,
                                           i+8,
                                           i+9,
                                           i+10,
                                           i+11))
```

I searched in the doc and on SO, but I didn't find anything about it. Can someone help me?

Comment: Have you tried using `tkinter.ttk.Treeview.get_children`?

Comment: Yes, I know this method, but I don't know what to eventually do with the results.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, I finally found how to do it, for example to display all values :

```py
for line in self.tree.get_children():

    for value in self.tree.item(line)['values']:
        print(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you want to access the values of the tree rather than the text. I'll explain the difference later.

If you have a parent-child hierarchy, you use this code:

```
for parent in self.tree.get_children():
    print(self.tree.item(parent)["values"])
    for child in self.tree.get_children(parent):
        print(self.tree.item(child)["values"])
```

If you have a simple hierarchy, you use this code:

```
for parent in self.tree.get_children():
    print(self.tree.item(parent)["values"])
```

Now, you get the logic and you can go wild with parent-child-subchild hierarchy.

In addition to this, you might want to populate the tree via loop, instead of repeating the same code:

```
self.tree['columns'] = ('Pool ID','Time', 'Lat', 'Lon', 'Alt', 'Spd', 'hdop','vdop','pdop', 'Sats Used', 'FixMode')
for column in self.tree['columns']:
    # define the column names and headings
    self.tree.column(column, width=90, anchor='center')
    self.tree.heading(column, text=column)
```

Then, you might want to insert the data into the tree. You can do this also via loop, which is much more compact:

```
# let's replicate your example data set
data = [[i+k+1  for k in range(11)] for i in range(5)]
for r, row in data:
    self.tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=f"{str(r)}", text='', values=row)
```

Explanation:
Now you can grab the values with `print(self.tree.item(parent)["values"])`, and if you use `"text"` instead of `"values"`, you get whatever you defined in the `text` field in the `self.tree.insert` method.
The `iid` defines the unique id of the entry in the tree: this is inserted programmatically. You can eventually fill the field `text` and get the content later.
I left the field `parent` blank in this simple case. But if you have a parent-child hierarchy you should name it.

For example:

```
for p, parent_record in enumerate(data):
    self.tree.insert(parent='', ...)  # can leave this blank
    for r, row in enumerate(parent_record['rows']):
        self.tree.insert(parent=f"{str(p)}", ...)  # any reference to parent loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```py
for Parent in self.treeview.get_children():

    print(self.treeview.item(Parent)["text"])

    for child in self.treeview.get_children(Parent):
        data = self.treeview.item(child)["text"]
        print(data)
```